# Establish HTTPS connection using custom certificate

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, https

How can I establish a HTTPS connection, using ASIHTTPRequest or just plain NSHTTPRequest, using a custom certificate on the phone to establish that connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With NSURLConnection / NSURLRequest

Implement the method `-(BOOL)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace:(NSURLProtectionSpace *)space` at your NSURLConnection delegate, check if the certificate (space) is okay, then return YES.

For ASIHTTPRequest you might check [this page](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use).